# onCharacteristicChanged not always catched with Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an issue that I don't know how to solve it.

I can successfully connect to a device, register to get notifications on a Characteristic and can successfully be notified once the value changed on the remote device.

The problem I got, is when successive notification arrives, the second is not always catched by the Service and even by the OS, because I only see this event the first time:

```
 2139-2398/? D/BtGatt.btif﹕ btgattc_handle_event:Event 1013 
 2139-2398/? D/BtGatt.btif﹕btif_gattc_upstreams_evt: Event 10
```

I don't like to say it but it works pretty good with an iPhone 5 ...

Even more weird, it works on my Samsung S4, but not on a Nexus5, S3 or Xperia T.
But, it seems that it depends of the amount of work it is done on the onCharacteristicChanged method (It takes about 100ms or less to do all the job).
So I wondering if there are some thing to avoid doing on ble service ?

My only lead for now, is to change Notify by Indicate, but I can't start to do this job without being sure that this will fix the problem because of the amount of work to to it...

I don't see why the OS won't catch this event.

Comment: 100ms is a lot of work to be doing on the callback.  Try just capturing the necessary data and posting to do the work on a different thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what I've tried since I've posted this question. So I've placed all the work in a new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable(){...})). But the result was exactly the same... I may have found the reason why my service wasn't working properly on a N5/Xperia T. I guess it was because once I get registered to the proper Characteristic to receive notifications the embeded ble module was pushing me a notification, in what I immediatly wrote in the Characteristic some value. But the result was my process to register on all wanted Characteristic was not finished yet, and I was never receiving the onCharacteristicWrite() callback. Since I've delayed the writeCharacteristic method everything fall back in work. I didn't explain why I received only one Notify before ... It was working on a S4 because of the amount of work was more important on a s4 on the first notify. Hope this will help someone else. The community of ble developper is not so big and google does not take ble very important I found... Hope everything will change in the futur.

**UPDATE**: A definitly better solution is to register the characteristic you know you will receive notification at first is to register it at the end of all needed characteristic.